# How and why other wrapper objects do not use constant pool in java

Tags: java

To save on memory, Java 'reuses' all the wrapper objects whose values fall in the following ranges.
All Boolean values (`true` and `false`)

All Byte values

All Character values from `\u0000` to `\u007f` (i.e. `0` to `127` in decimal)

All Short and Integer values from `-128` to `127`.
Eg:

```
Integer i1=7;
Integer i2=7;
System.out.println(i1==i2);//true
```

What about for Double,Long and how different in using constant pool ?
Eg:

```
Double d1=7.2;
Double d2=7.2;
System.out.println(d1==d2);//false
```

Comment: Only commonly used values are saved in the constant pool. Long values are a lot less common than small integers, and there is no common pattern in the use of double values at all.

Comment: Because there are a lot of `Long`s and `Double`s?

Comment: There are 2 possible Boolean Values. There are 256 Integers in the range from -128 to 127. How many doubles are there in that range? Simply to many and choosing values which will often get used so that caching them makes sense isn't really an easy task.

Comment: Your example for doubles isn't necessarily the case. The API allows for values to ["(cache) frequently requested values"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#valueOf(double)).

Answer (score 2):

The precision of floating point numbers is limited; but think back to your days in school; when you learned maths, and you heard about [real numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_number) ...

In that sense, my answer is a question to you: can you tell us how many numbers to cache between, say 0.01 and 0.02?!

And of course: the answer is - there is an unlimited number of real numbers between any two floating point numbers. Thus there is absolutely **no** way of **caching** those numbers.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion `Double` and `Float` have to many values to reason don't let them mantain the cashe, in other words it is uneffective.

`Long` and `Boolean` also have their cashes (in case of `Boolean` it is simple two final variables `false` and `true`)